# Create two return variants of object properties

Tags: typescript

Assume input:

```
const in = {name: 'hi'}
```

processed by function X that returns two output versions:

```
const out = {nameRaw: ref('hi'), nameResult: ref(ok('hi')} // ok = neverthrow
```

Adding typing to out:

1. errors but desired (errors to individual parts of line 3):

   ```
   type funcOuta<Type extends funcInObj> = {
     [Property in keyof Type as `${Property & string}Raw`]: Ref<Type[Property]>
     [Property in keyof Type as `${Property & string}Result`]: Ref<Result<Type[Property]>,Error>>
   };
   ```
2. no errors but undesired as Raw out can be of same type as Result out (and thus requires type narrowing when using the outputs = undesired)

   ```
   type funcOutb<Type extends DtoUscResp> = {
     [Property in keyof Type as `${Property & string}${'Raw' | 'Result'}`]:
       | Ref<Type[Property]>
       | Ref<Result<Type[Property]>,Error>>;
   };
   ```
3. How to properly type funcout such that each raw and result variant has its own corresponding type? -> answered, see @tobias

________________________ added later ________________

4. how to get a functionning complete example?The following code gives a TS error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'funcOut<Type>'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'funcOut<Type>'`.  -> unanswered

[full code:](https://CgAawgQPxgoR0F2WigAAwASPF8AiCCQWToGJm4AJXYAdyTmGjiIH39A0FZtGXd8Lwy6nJJwyOjYpygE5LS2rOC5dQLCiFo4ABtgcpp0NHYQBycazOzmV21+PuApsVxLJBtgWzxFFSoAcigD+hvuZ15eE+AiP1CADTXBSgOZESJ3QGGcAAphDQQZgAJRUE5nP4ufDNGYQMQREBULE9Kq5caaXhIL70KBoKYIyRIqquXB4bQDRF2WnNGB+NDgrFQHpWABGACsIEhgAA6LG0SEIMCw2HNDzy+TkqYELEAahuxRKN1YuGEqsizEV8gptANIA1k2mcx14gQEBKUCWKylYHNzDlSqgfCVFOAcDQoVNzV4fGJpLEwlENCjwHpV1UNwewCe4YQZL8ohJKnEv1jENjcpJ6b86NFMz8GHBmeA2YgsKAA)

```
type funcArg = {[index: string] : any}
type input = funcArg &  {name: string} // {name:hi}
type funcOut<Type> = 
  {  [Property in keyof Type as `${Property & string}Raw`]: Type[Property] } &
  {  [Property in keyof Type as `${Property & string}Result`]: Array<Type[Property]> } 
type test = funcOut<{name:' test'}> // yeey, type as expected!! credits @Tobias 

function X<Type extends funcArg>(inp: funcArg):funcOut<Type> {
  let key:keyof Type & string
const res:funcOut<Type> = {} as funcOut<Type>
  for(key of Object.keys(inp))
    {
      res[key+'Raw'] = inp[key] // tserror
      res[key+'Result'] = new Array(inp[key]) // tserror
    }
   return res
  
}

const input: input= {name:'test'}
const outcome = X<input>(input)
console.log(outcome) // correct: {nameRaw": "test","nameResult": ["test"]}
```

Comment: You probably meant to use an intersection: `{
  [Property in keyof Type as `${Property & string}Raw`]: Ref<Type[Property]> } & { [Property in keyof Type as `${Property & string}Result`]: Ref<Result<Type[Property]>,Error>> }` but that is just guess work without a minimum reproducable example.

Comment: @TobiasS. Thanks, that did the trick, now the type definition for out is correct!!

Comment: @TobiasS. I tried to make a full working example but unfortunately did not succeed with the assignment of the `res` var in `function X`, could you help here as well? :)

Comment: i would be asking what you gain from dynamic property names. in `T`, out `[Ref<T>, Ref<Result<T>>]` or `{ raw: Ref<T>, result: Ref<Result<T>> }` and move on with your life

Comment: @Mulan, could you explain? In reality the added objects properties are returned by a usecase (DDD) to the presenter. `T` represents the DTO which is defined in each usecase. Each usecase extends a baseusecase class which has (apart from logging, notifications, loading indicators,... ) also the functionality to provide a 1. ref<T> and 2.ref<result<T>>. 1. is 90% of the times sufficiet in the presenter as I just need reactive data and am not interested in handling the result (neverthrow) property, 10% of the time I want to do additional work depending on the outcome of 2.

Comment: @user1345112 dynamic properties are a code smell. i can't remember the last time i encountered them where a simpler solution couldn't be applied. you don't always have to think in terms of `extends`. using `type Whatever<T> = {raw: Ref<T>, result: Ref<Result<T>>}` you could use `Array<Whatever<T>>` to represent a collection of them, or `{foo: Whatever<T>, bar: Whatever<T>}` or `{foo: Whatever<string>, bar: Whatever<boolean>}`, to express more complex types.